# Using static keyword in objective-c when defining a cached variable

Tags: objective-c, caching, static

I'm looking at the following apple example source code:

```
    /*
 Cache the formatter. Normally you would use one of the date formatter styles (such as NSDateFormatterShortStyle), but here we want a specific format that excludes seconds.
 */
static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = nil;
if (dateFormatter == nil) {
    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
}
```

Trying to figure out:

- Why use the static keyword?
- How this equates to a cached variable if you set it to nil each time the method is called.

The code is from Example 4 in the [Tableview Suite demo](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableViewSuite/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Static variables retain their assigned values over repeated calls to the function. They're basically like global values that are only "visible" to that function.

The initializer statement is only executed once however.

This code initializes `dateFormatter` to `nil` the first time the function is used. On every subsequent call to the function a check is made against value of `dateFormatter`. If it's not set (which will only be true the first time) a a new `dateFormatter` is created. If it is set then the `static dateFormatter` variable will be used instead.

It's worth becoming familiar with `static` variables. They can be very convenient but have downsides too (in this example it's impossible to release the `dateFormatter` object for example).

Just a tip: Sometimes it can be educational to place a breakpoint in the code and have a look to see what's going on. As the complexity of your programs increase this will become an invaluable skill.

Comment: Hi @Andrew Grant, very nice explanation, In this case , as you have mentioned that, it is impossible to release it, suppose I want to release it and assign a new value to date formatter, then how it should be done.

Answer (score 16):

"`static`" functionally means "don't evaluate the stuff on the right side of the equals sign every time through, use its previous value instead" in this case.

Use this great power with great responsibility: you run the risk of using a whole ton of memory, since these are objects that never go away. It's rarely appropriate except for in cases like this one with `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: i know this is OLD question but wondering the impact of this static keyword in relation with ARC?

Comment: @codejunkie statics are stored in a different location than the heap. ARC concerns retaining and releasing heap memory so that values can persist beyond stack frames. Therefore, I doubt ARC has any effect on static variables.

Answer (score 1):

For reference purposes, this is how I am using the static for my date formatter for using in a table view controller.

```
+ (NSDateFormatter *) relativeDateFormatter
{
     static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
     static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
     dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
         //NSLog(@"Created");
         dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
         [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
         [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
         NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
         [dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
         [dateFormatter setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES];
     });
     return dateFormatter;
}
```