# How to use class variables in objective-c like "MyClassName.var"?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to declare static-class variables in objective-c class and want to use them directly using class name like

E.g

having a class named "Myclassname" and variable "Var"

and want access this variable like this....

Myclassname.Var=@"hi";

I dont want to use getters and setters.

Any help please?

Comment: Not possible. [Take a look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695980/how-do-i-declare-class-level-properties-in-objective-c).

Comment: For accessing static ivars from external you should use accessors. Keep in mind that the accessors start with a prefix + and not - because they are class methods rather than instance methods. If you var is `int _abc;` and your getter is `+(int)abc;` then and your Class is `A` then you access the getter `with `[A abc]; I am not sure whether `A.abc` would work too. Don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Variables aren't accessed using the `.` syntax - those are getters and setters. Your only option, as @bbarnhart points out, is to manually declare class getters and setters.

```
@interface Myclassname

+(NSString *)var;
+(void)setVar:(NSString *)newVar;

@end
```

And implement these methods to access/set the backing `static` variable.

This isn't really a good idea, anyway, and doesn't jive with Objective-C style. You should consider using a [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-should-my-objective-c-singleton-look-like) and properties, instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you can't use the -> syntax like this:

```
Myclassname->var = @"Hi";
```