# Call a method across classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, methods

I have two view's in my app. In the first view I have a table view which displays data downloaded from the Internet. The `FirstViewController` has a method to get the data and update the view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Create PlanGenerator
    _planGenerator = [[PlanGenerator alloc] init]

    [self loadPlan];

- (void)loadPlan
{
    _plan = [_planGenerator getData]

    // Updating the view

    // Updating the table view
    [self.tableView reloadData]
}
```

To download the data from the internet I have a class called `PlanGenerator`. This class has an instance method called `getData`, it returns an NSArray. The table view uses the instance variable `_plan` (array) to display data in the table view.

In the second view (controlled by the `SecondViewController`) you can make some adjustments on what to download. To tell these change the `PlanGenerator` I used the concept of [class properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695980/how-do-i-declare-class-level-properties-in-objective-c). Now when I changed something in the second view (actually it's just one parameter) I want to call the method `loadPlan` from the `FirstViewController`.

My first thought was to create a class method, but then I would have to creat "class properties" for every variable the method uses.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: A couple of things....  When you say "second view", do you actually mean second view controller? (There's a **big** difference.)  Are you aware that `alloc/init` creates a **new** object which won't have information that you've given to some other `PlanGenerator` in some other piece of code?

Comment: Yes I know that this is a big difference, but I thought it was obvious that any View has also a ViewController. Anyway I added that in my question. But I don't really understand what you mean with the second part of your question. I know that every new object of `PlanGenerator` is different, but the data that is returned by `getData` is the same for every instance.

Comment: Some people have multiple views in a single controller and hide/show them as necessary.  (*shrug*)  I see you've changed your question so that the `PlanGenerator` isn't a local variable.  That helps with the second part of my comment; I was talking about how you were going to call `loadPlan` on something that would go out of scope at the end of the method.

Comment: Ok now I understand, yes the _planGenerator and _plan (array) are instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some basics.

Try this design, assuming that FirstVC is used to display data and has tableview. SecondVC (your PlanGenerator) is used to get/download data.

In SecondVC:

1. Create whatever property(parameter, etc. says criteria) that FirstVC will supply to decide what to download.
2. Create a public method getData.

In FirstVC:

1. Create an iVar (says _myPlanGeneartor) and allocate it.

Now from the instance of FirstVC, you have access to an instance of SecondVC (_myPlanGenerator).  With that you can supply criteria parameter and request data (getData).

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I think I didn't express myself well. I have 2 ViewControllers (in the MVC pattern the Controllers) and I have the PlanGenerator class (in the MVC pattern the Model). That's actually my structure.

Comment: Do you have another idea?