# ObjectiveC: convention to define reusable identifier

Tags: objective-c

I'm pretty new to Objective-C and trying to figure out what is the accepted convention to define a reusable identifier for either collection / table view cell.

In Swift, I've seen something like

```
class SomeCell: UITableViewCell {
  static let identifier = "SomeCell"
  // ... other
}
```

How do Objective-C developers deal with this?

Comment: You are looking for "Class property". it's the key words equivalent in Objective-C for `static let/var`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I declare class-level properties in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695980/how-do-i-declare-class-level-properties-in-objective-c)