# Memoization in static Objective-C class

Tags: c++, iphone, c, objective-c, memoization

Say I have a class method like

```
+ (double)function:(id)param1 :(id)param2
{
   // I want to memoize this like...
   static NSMutableDictionary* cache = nil;
   //
   // test if (param1,param2) is in cache and return cached value, etc. etc
   //
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554969/using-static-keyword-in-objective-c-when-defining-a-cached-variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create the cache once and check against it, I generally use an [`+initialize`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/initialize) method. This method is called before the first message sent to the class, so the cache would be created before `+function::` (which, by the way, is a terrible selector name) could be called. In this case, I usually declare the cache variable in the .m file, but declaring it in the method definition may also work.

---

**Edit:** Adding an example at request of OP:

```
// MyClass.m

static NSMutableDictionary* cache;

+ (void) initialize {
    cache = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}

+ (double) cachedValueForParam1:(id)param1 param2:(id)param2 {
    // Test if (param1,param2) is in cache and return cached value.
}
```

Obviously, if a value doesn't exist in the cache, you should have some code that adds the value. Also, I have no idea how you intend to combine `param1` and `param2` as the key for the cache, or how you'll store the value. (Perhaps `+[NSNumber numberWithDouble:]` and `-[NSNumber doubleValue]`?) You'll want to make sure you understand dictionary lookups before implementing such a strategy.

Comment: Obviously the names are generic lol. Could you provide an example of creating the variable in +initialize as it is not an instance member variable.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach.  It's not multi-threaded safe, nor is it safe to call `+initialize` multiple times (which can happen via sub-classes calling `[super initialize]`).

Comment: Certainly, there are ways you could make the method "safer", I just didn't want to overcomplicate the answer or overwhelm the OP. And honestly, it's a cache, so while replacing an existing dictionary would be a mistake and cause leaks, it would be easy to work around such a problem. For example, my `+initialize` generally checks (and often synchronizes on) `[self class]` before doing anything. Best practice is wonderful, but let's not throw every possible error case at a simple question, shall we?

Answer (score 2):

I use something like the following.  Unlike the version posted by @Quinn Taylor, this version has the following properties:

- Creates a `NSAutoreleasePool` to guarantee that a pool exists.  Best to assume the worst when dealing with 'start-up' like code.  Harmless if a pool already exists.
- Creates `cache` exactly once:

  - Safe to call `+initialize` multiple times (may happen via sub-classing).
  - Multi-threaded safe. No matter how many threads concurrently call `+initialize` at the exact same time, `cache` is guaranteed to only be created once.  The thread that 'wins' the atomic CAS retains `cache`, the threads that 'loose' `autorelease` their attempts.

If you want to be *extremely* conservative, you can add assertion checks that both `pool` and `initCache` are not `NULL`.  Also note that this does nothing to ensure that `cache` is used in a multi-threaded safe way once it's been created.

```
#include <libkern/OSAtomic.h>

static NSMutableDictionary *cache;

+ (void)initialize
{
  NSAutoreleasePool   *pool      = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  NSMutableDictionary *initCache = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
  _Bool                didSwap   = false;

  while((cache == NULL) && ((didSwap = OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(NULL, initCache, (void * volatile)&cache)) == false)) { /* Allows for spurious CAS failures. */ }
  if(didSwap == true) { [cache retain]; }

  [pool release];
  pool = NULL;
}
```

Comment: +1 Those are good checks, and ones that I do in my own code. I left them out for simplicity, but they're a logical extension. The autorelease pool is a toss-up for me, since I always have on in `main()`, but may be applicable if one's code is used by third parties. For subclasses, I generally protect with `-isMemberOfClass:`, and for multi-threading I use @synchronized blocks on `[self class]` for simplicity. Still, good to include in a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to do and whether thread safety is an issue, you may also want to consider a singleton class as in [the answer to this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like).

Comment: Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986736/nsmutabledictionary-thread-safety on NSMutableDictionary thread safety.