# Do we need to release constants?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring

How does a constant declared as below in the implementation part of a class is released:

```
static NSString *myconst = @"some data...";
```

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568691/how-to-release-static-objective-c-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to release it. The string literals reside in the executable's data section, not in the dynamically allocated memory (AKA heap).

There's no harm in accidentally calling `release` though. I'm pretty sure the literals are wired to quietly ignore that call.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to release strings created with `@""`. You only need to release objects created with `alloc`, `retain`, `copy` or `new`.

Answer (score 1):

retain, release and autorelease messages to strings of the above kind are ignored.

Read Apple's memory management docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)

However one thing to note here is passing release crashes the app. Hence the usual idea being, if you haven't used alloc or retain on the string, don't attempt to release it.

Also read this useful link [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSString) which explains the same thing.